# Deploying VueJS on google cloud

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-platform, cloud, web-deployment, vue-cli-3

I am using Vue CLI 3 to create a web application with the following presets: babel, PWA, Vue Router, and css proprocessors. I am trying to deploy the application on Google Cloud's App Engine. How do I serve this? The tutorial on Google says I just have to do:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

in the root directory, but I don't know how to configure app.yaml to deploy the dist/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deploying your Vue.js app to Google App Engine using Cloud Build? I have had no problem deploying any Vue.js apps in this way. Try following this tutorial for [complete instructions.](https://medium.com/@brian.young.pro/how-to-deploy-vue-js-app-to-google-cloud-with-cloud-build-ad104bb1cf60)

Basically, you would have to include the following two files in your project root directory when deploying your Vue.js app to Google App Engine via Cloud Build:

1. App.yaml

```html
runtime: nodejs10
handlers:
  # Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$ 
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
  # catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

and

2. cloudbuild.yaml

```html
steps:
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["install"]
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["run", "build"]
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

In the case you're not using cloud build you may just reference the app.yaml above and the configuration should be sufficient for your case.

Comment: Please don't write link-only answers.

Comment: @highfivebrian for it show Status 
Step failed
Name 
gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud